# MongoClient cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, mongodb

I am new to MongoDB and I want to establish connection with my mongod server.
But I get the error `MongoClient cannot be resolved to a type` I have included external Jar into my project but still cannot fix the error

Here is my code I think there is no error in my code but I have included wrong JAR file in my project

```
import com.mongodb.*;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class Dining {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Lock forks[] = new ReentrantLock[5];

try {
    MongoClient mongoClient = new  MongoClient("mongo");
    System.out.println("Connection to mongodb successful.");
    DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "mydb" );
    System.out.println("Database 'mydb' created.");
    DBCollection coll = db.createCollection("mycol", null);
    System.out.println("Collection 'mycol' created.");
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

   for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
    forks[i] = new ReentrantLock(); 
}

Thread p1 = new Thread(new Philosopher(forks[4], forks[0], "first"));
Thread p2 = new Thread(new Philosopher(forks[0], forks[1], "second"));
Thread p3 = new Thread(new Philosopher(forks[1], forks[2], "third"));
Thread p4 = new Thread(new Philosopher(forks[2], forks[3], "fourth"));
Thread p5 = new Thread(new Philosopher(forks[3], forks[4], "fifth"));

p1.start();
p2.start();
p3.start();
p4.start();
p5.start(); 


}
}

class Philosopher implements Runnable {
Lock leftFork = new ReentrantLock();
Lock rightFork = new ReentrantLock();
String name;


public Philosopher(Lock leftFork, Lock rightFork, String name) {
this.leftFork = leftFork;
this.rightFork = rightFork;
this.name = name; 
}

@Override
public void run() {
try {
think(name);
eat(leftFork, rightFork, name); 
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}

private void eat(Lock leftFork, Lock rightFork, String name) throws Exception{
leftFork.lock();
rightFork.lock();
try
{
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost");
DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "mydb" );
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("mycol");

System.out.println(name + " eating...");
BasicDBObject doc1 = new BasicDBObject(name , " eating...");
coll.insert(doc1);

    Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
finally{
    System.out.println(name + " done eating and now thinking...");
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost");
    DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "mydb" );
    DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("mycol");
    BasicDBObject doc2 = new BasicDBObject(name , " done eating and now thinking...");
    coll.insert(doc2);
    leftFork.unlock();
    rightFork.unlock(); 
}
}

public void think(String name) throws Exception{
try
{
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost");
DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "mydb" );
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("mycol");
System.out.println(name + " thinking...");
BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject(name , " thinking...");
coll.insert(doc);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
}

}
```

Comment: Which dependencies manager are you using?

Comment: I figured it out I used the wrong dependencies we must use mongo-java-driver-2.10.1 dependencies. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Cheers, a vote up will be nice @Akshay Naik

Answer (score 0):

Adding:

```
# mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar 
# mongob-driver-3.4.2
```

to my `Web-content > WEB-INF > lib` folder in Eclipse Luna solved my problem. Use the latest driver available, the ones listed are the latest at the time of posting this.

Comment: Can you explain why adding this fixed the problem? This helps others learn from your answer, rather than just copy it without understanding why.

Answer (score 0):

I think `MongoDatabase` class file not available in the `mongodb-driver-3.8.0-beta3` jar file. That is why you are unable to import it. You can use stable version `3.7.1 of mongo jar`. MongoDatabase class is available in stable version. Source : [mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.7.1](http://I%20think%20MongoDatabase%20class%20file%20not%20available%20in%20the%20mongodb-driver-3.8.0-beta3%20jar%20file.%20That%20is%20why%20you%20are%20unable%20to%20import%20it.%20You%20can%20use%20stable%20version%203.7.1%20of%20mongo%20jar.%20MongoDatabase%20class%20is%20available%20in%20stable%20version.%20Source%20:%20mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.7.1)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add MongoDB Synchronous Driver to your dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
</dependency>
```